# SQL help with MAX query

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, ora-00979

I have a table of countries named bbc(name, region, area, population, gdp)

I want a table with the region, name and population of the largest ( most populated) countries by region. So far i've tried this:

```
SELECT region, name, MAX(population)
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region
```

It gave me an error message : ORA-00979: Not a GROUP BY Expression

I tried to change to GROUP BY region, name, but it doesn't give me the right table

Comment: What's going on with the 2nd `MAX(population)`? Where have you seen that done?

Comment: OK, but don't let it happen again :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the easiest and shortest way to do it, since Oracle has tuple testing, it can make the code shorter:

First, get the max population on each region:

```
SELECT region, MAX(population)
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region
```

Then test the countries against it:

```
select region, name, population 
from bbc 
where (region, population) in
      (SELECT region, MAX(population)
       FROM bbc
       GROUP BY region)
order by region
```

If you want to support many RDBMS, use EXISTS:

```
select region, name, population 
from bbc o
where exists
      (SELECT null -- neutral. doesn't invoke Cargo Cult Programming ;-)
       FROM bbc
       WHERE region = o.region 
       GROUP BY region
       HAVING o.population = MAX(population) )
order by region
```

Query tested here, both have similar output: http://sqlzoo.net/0.htm

http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/05/why-is-exists-select-1-cargo-cult.html

Comment: Both of these queries have a higher cost (Explain Plan) than the query using analytics. It all depends on your goals.

Comment: Is that proof-by-blatant assertion ;-) what are we doing pre-analytics? I could hazard a guess that there's more computer science stuff thrown on that approach than the analytics, that functionality exists long way before those CTE/Windowing/Analytics came to the scene. C/C++ implementation-wise, analytics has many **ifs** inside, it handles many functionalities, so  could it be slower? maybe. Just my 2 cents. The answer is to profile

Comment: Nowhere near proof - simply an observation of what the optimizer thinks the query will cost to execute. You're absolutely correct that the proof is in the metrics.

Answer (score 7):

You can use analytics for queries like that:

```
SELECT name, region, population
  FROM (SELECT region, name, population
             , MAX(population) OVER (PARTITION BY region) maxpop
          FROM bbc)
 WHERE population = maxpop;
```

The inline view gives you a table that looks like your base table, plus an extra column with the max population for the region. Your top-level select gives you the country, region and population of the largest country in each region.

To illustrate with a limited example:

```
SELECT * FROM bbc;

REGION          NAME        POPULATION
--------------- -------     ----------
North America   USA         300000000
North America   Canada      100000000
North America   Mexico       50000000
South America   Brazil       50000000
South America   Argentina    40000000
South America   Venezuela    20000000
```

Add the analytic function:

```
SELECT region, NAME, population
     , MAX(population) OVER (PARTITION BY region) maxpop
  FROM bbc;

REGION          NAME                POPULATION      MAXPOP
--------------- -------             ----------      ----------
North America   USA                 300000000       300000000
North America   Canada              100000000       300000000
North America   Mexico               50000000       300000000
South America   Brazil               50000000        50000000
South America   Argentina            40000000        50000000
South America   Venezuela            20000000        50000000
```

Then the finished product:

```
NAME    REGION             POPULATION
------- ---------------    -----------
USA     North America       300000000
Brazil  South America        50000000
```

One more edit. You can avoid a nest select, but not a subquery:

```
SELECT NAME, region, population
  FROM bbc
 WHERE (region, population) IN
       (SELECT region, MAX(population)
          FROM bbc
         group by region);
```

Comment: For a given region, if two countries have the same population (which is highly unlikely I think, but it is always worth asking), this query will return both: is this what tiagovrtr is waiting for?

Comment: Who knows? Not in the requirements!

Comment: @BrunoGautier sure, it does the job, but i was trying not to use nested selects. Is it impossible?

Comment: @OMG, there's always more than one way to do it ;-) I wonder if there's a performance difference....

Comment: @tiagovtr, not sure why you want to avoid nested selects, but my edit shows how to do it with a subquery.

Comment: @tiagovrtr, why not nested selects? I think that queries with nested selects are usually more readable because you can more easily see the steps involved to get to the final result, especially when using analytics. And I also find it easier to guess the execution plan.

Comment: @OMG, I was indeed thinking about using the <code>ROW_NUMBER</code> function ;-)

Comment: @DCookie, I like your illustration, it shows very well the reasoning behind the use of analytics.

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of vases, the ORA-00979 error is caused because a non-aggregated column is not included in the GROUP BY clause.  In this case you need to include **name** as well in your GROUP BY clause. Also, you should not be calling the MAX function in your FROM statement.

```
SELECT region, name, MAX(population)
FROM bbc
GROUP BY region, name
```